# Using jQuery to generate wrapping DIVs once page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are working with a CMS that generates the following HTML:

```
<h3 class="heading">Heading 1</h3>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>More content</div>
  <div>Even more content</div>
<h3 class="heading">Heading 2</h3>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some more content</div>
<h3 class="heading">Heading 3</h3>
  <div>Other content</div>
```

Unfortunately we can't easily change this structure but we want to add the following divs to be used in an accordion style dynamic layout:

```
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="heading">Heading 1</h3>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>More content</div>
    <div>Even more content</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="heading">Heading 2</h3>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some more content</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="heading">Heading 3</h3>
    <div>Other content</div>
</div>
```

I was wondering how to add wrapping divs once the page is loaded using jQuery.

The code would have to walk the DOM, identify h3.heading and then create a wrapping parent div around the heading and all the following divs.

Or is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TK6ay/1/

```
$('.heading').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.heading').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="section"/>');
});
```

Comment: Tried to make it a one liner with no luck. Nice one. `$('h3.heading, h3.heading+div, h3.heading+div+div').wrapAll('<div class="section "/>');​​​`

Comment: Haha - I was distracted by my child - good timing.  Yours is ever so slightly better than mine in that you use `.heading` (I didn't pay attention to the class on the h3).  You should create a closed div element though ;)

Comment: Fantastic, what a clean solution. Thank you.

Comment: There is one possible problem, in the last group, there is nothing to tell nextUntil to stop collecting elements since there are no more elements with the class heading.  You might want/need to add some elements to the selector:  $(this).nextUntil('.heading, a, input')...   I blogged about this here: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2012/04/06/elegance-thy-name-is-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This should be exactly what you need:

```
(function($) {
    $('h3').each(function() {
       $(this).nextUntil('h3').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="section"/>');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SFVQP/